# Why we need service discovery in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

To tell Prometheus what to monitor, we will provide it with Node exporter details. In that case, I couldn't get the actual reason why we need the service discovery in that case?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you providing the details is the service discovery, presumably via static or file_sd.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is why do prometheus needs discovery, that is very easy.

Let's say you have a Kubernetes cluster on gcp (GKE) the number of nodes, compute instances, can change a lot.

The discovery service will allow us to only give specific details using the gcp specific discovery item with a tag or something else.

This way you don't have to be behind your computer to check if the cluster number of instance is moving.

Answer (score 0):

## Why not just use local configuration ? (rather than service discovery)

Nowadays one don't want to manage the list of services to monitor manually : there are too many services, the services are changing too often, etc.

Also, we usually have proper configuration management tools nowadays (pick any of your favorite tools...  docker, kubernetes, Puppet, Ansible...), those typically have a central inventory of the services (actually, not just an inventory but descriptions of the configurations and top-down management tool).

So options are:

1. Manage the list of agents manually
2. The monitoring solution has a database of services to monitor : one have to implement a solution to synchronize central inventory with the monitoring solution.
3. The monitoring solution has no database of services to monitor :the monitoring simply fetch the up-to-date list of services from the central inventory (kubernetes, Puppet... or CMDB for those how have one that is up to date).

Note: Prometheus don't intend to support each and every possible service registry natively. Rather, it is recommended to generate a [YAML](https://prometheus.io/blog/2015/06/01/advanced-service-discovery/) or [JSON](https://www.robustperception.io/using-json-file-service-discovery-with-prometheus) by querying your favorite service registry.

## Service discovery & the Push-vs-Pull dilemma

Some people advocate that monitoring agents should simply push metrics to  monitoring platform configured locally on the server (i.e push metrics rather than mull from the monitoring platform). I won't rephrase the whole discussion here (see [Push needs Service Discovery](https://www.robustperception.io/push-needs-service-discovery) and [Why do you pull rather than push?](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/faq/#why-do-you-pull-rather-than-push))

One of the point (by Brian Brazil from Robust-Perception) is that monitoring is often about CHECKING : checking what you know you have deployed, why it's deployed, how it should behave, why it should behave in a certain way (which application, which pattern use...). So the monitoring platform has to be configured with the list of service and expected state.